# How do I check a key exists in a hashtable in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, hashtable

At the moment I initialize as follows:

```
$my_hash = array();
```

Populate like this:

```
$my_hash[$key] = $value;
```

However when I check for my key as follows

```
if ($my_hash[$key])
```

The server throws up an error. How to I check for my key?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if(array_key_exists($key, $my_hash)){
    // do your stuff
}
```

It's not exactly a hash table. It's an array data type in PHP.

More operations on arrays can be seen here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: How are hashtables and associative arrays (at least in PHP) different?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

```
if(array_key_exists($key, $hashtable)){
    // item is in the hastable
}
```